# Exception is ocurring while Implementing Azure Service bus at Receiver End

Tags: asp.net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

While Implementing Azure Service bus encountering an issue at the receiver end code, I had created two Asp.net core projects in same solution.

```
string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://vm-qa-testsb.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=IdReihr0Df1W99";
                string queueName = "messages-topic";
                // since ServiceBusClient implements IAsyncDisposable we create it with "await using"
                await using var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

                // create the sender
                ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(queueName);

                // create a message that we can send. UTF-8 encoding is used when providing a string.
                ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage("Hello world!");

                // send the message
                await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
```

The above code is at Sender.

```
string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://vm-qa-testsb.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=Ihr0Df18w=";
string queueName = "messages-topic";
// since ServiceBusClient implements IAsyncDisposable we create it with "await using"
await using var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

// create a receiver that we can use to receive the message
ServiceBusReceiver receiver = client.CreateReceiver(queueName);

// the received message is a different type as it contains some service set properties
ServiceBusReceivedMessage receivedMessage = await receiver.ReceiveMessageAsync();

// get the message body as a string
string body = receivedMessage.Body.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(body);
```

the above code is at receiver end.

While running the project an exception is throwing.

```
Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The messaging entity 'vm-qa-testsb:Topic:messages-topic|amqps://vm-qa-testsb.servicebus.windows.net/-bc2998f2;0:5:6:source(address:/messages-topic,filter:[])' could not be found. To know more visit https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions.  TrackingId:2424f501-e917-4668-a161-bd4e2d46a6ea_B2, SystemTracker:gi::G17:645706134:amqps://vm-qa-testsb.servicebus.windows.net/-bc2998f2;0:5:6:source(address:/messages-topic,filter:[]), bi::in-connection66(G17-623307177)::session389::link656105, Timestamp:2024-03-22T12:43:02 TrackingId:5d5cfbc3ff6c4e18904956841887d341_G17, SystemTracker:gateway7, Timestamp:2024-03-22T12:43:02 (MessagingEntityNotFound). For troubleshooting information, see https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/servicebus/exceptions/troubleshoot.
  Source=Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus
  StackTrace:
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpReceiver.<ReceiveMessagesAsyncInternal>d__45.MoveNext()
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpReceiver.<>c.<<ReceiveMessagesAsync>b__44_0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusRetryPolicy.<RunOperation>d__23`2.MoveNext()
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusRetryPolicy.<RunOperation>d__23`2.MoveNext()
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpReceiver.<ReceiveMessagesAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceiver.<ReceiveMessagesAsync>d__42.MoveNext()
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceiver.<ReceiveMessagesAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceiver.<ReceiveMessageAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
   at Program.<<Main>$>d__0.MoveNext() in
```

Comment: The variable is `queueName` but the value refers to a topic. Is it a topic or a queue? If it is a topic, you need to define the subscription name under that topic that you want to receive from.

Comment: @Sampath: Your first comment is blatently wrong.  There's no method `CreateQueueReceiver` nor concept of a different receiver for different entities.  There is just `ServiceBusReceiver` which works against either a queue or subscription.

Comment: Juunas is correct; you can receive from a queue but not from a topic.  To read messages sent to a topic, you'll need to create a subscription and point the receiver at it.